# What does `@` mean in YAML (which causes Psych::SyntaxError)?

Tags: ruby, yaml

Is `@` a reserved symbol in YAML? When I force it to be a string, everything is fine

```rb
require 'yaml'
k = "test: @hello"
YAML.load(k)
# => {"test"=>"@hello"}
```

But, if I write it without quotation, it gives me `Psych::SyntaxError`. Why is that? Does `@<something>` have some special meaning in YAML?

```rb
require 'yaml'
k = "test: @hello"
YAML.load(k)
# => Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From YAML spec, indicator characters ([link](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2772075)):

> The “@” (#x40, at) and “`” (#x60, grave accent) are reserved for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's reserved.  See Example 5.10 http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html